# How to animate with easeIn in UIKit sheet like a SwiftUI sheet?

Tags: swift, swiftui, uikit

My goal is to use a SwiftUI view as a sheet using UIKit navigation.

The problem is that the UIKit sheet animates `FeatureIView` from the *top left to the center*.

Meanwhile, SwiftUI sheet animates `FeatureIView` from the *center with the `easeIn` animation*.

My expectation is that the UIKit sheet animates from the center with `easeIn` animation.

My actual result is that the UIKit sheet animates from the top left to the center, which is unexpected.

**Current culprit**: `ScrollView` with UIKit navigation causes the animation to be unexpected.

SwiftUI version:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct Station {
    let name: String
    
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension Station: Identifiable {
    var id: String { name }
}

struct MRT {
    static let stations: [Station] = [
        .init("A"), .init("B"), .init("C"), .init("D"), .init("E"), .init("F"), .init("G"), .init("H"), .init("J"), .init("K")
    ]
}

struct FeatureIView: View {
    init() {
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(MRT.stations) { station in
                    Button {
            } label: {
                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: 8, height: 8)
                        Text("\(station.name) Station")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        Text(station.name)
                    }
                    .padding(8)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

final class FeatureFViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isPresented = true
    @Published var selection: PresentationDetent = .medium
    
    init() {
#if DEBUG
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
#endif
    }
    
    deinit {
#if DEBUG
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
#endif
    }
}

struct FeatureFView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var featureFViewModel: FeatureFViewModel
    
    init(featureFViewModel: FeatureFViewModel) {
        self.featureFViewModel = featureFViewModel
#if DEBUG
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
#endif
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Hello World")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $featureFViewModel.isPresented) {
            VStack {
                Text("Sheet")
                
                if featureFViewModel.selection == .large {
                    FeatureIView()
                } else {
                    Text("hello")
                }
            }
            .presentationDetents([.medium, .large], selection: $featureFViewModel.selection)
        }
    }
}
```

UIKit SceneDelegate:

```swift
    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
        // Use this method to optionally configure and attach the UIWindow `window` to the provided UIWindowScene `scene`.
        // If using a storyboard, the `window` property will automatically be initialized and attached to the scene.
        // This delegate does not imply the connecting scene or session are new (see `application:configurationForConnectingSceneSession` instead).
        guard let windowScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
        
        navigationController = UINavigationController()
        
        guard let navigationController else { return }
        
        let view = FeatureEView()
        let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: view)
        
        window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
        
        navigationController.pushViewController(viewController, animated: true)
        
        let featureFViewModel = FeatureFViewModel()
        let viewToPresent = FeatureFView(featureFViewModel: featureFViewModel)
        let viewControllerToPresent = UIHostingController(rootView: viewToPresent)
        
        guard let sheetController = viewControllerToPresent.sheetPresentationController else { return }
        
        sheetController.detents = [.medium(), .large()]
        sheetController.delegate = featureFViewModel
        
        navigationController.present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: true)
    }
```

UIKit with SwiftUI:

```
struct Station {
    let name: String
    
    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

extension Station: Identifiable {
    var id: String { name }
}

struct MRT {
    static let stations: [Station] = [
        .init("A"), .init("B"), .init("C"), .init("D"), .init("E"), .init("F"), .init("G"), .init("H"), .init("J"), .init("K")
    ]
}

struct FeatureIView: View {
    init() {
        print("\(type(of: self)) \(#function)")
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack(spacing: 20) {
                ForEach(MRT.stations) { station in
                    Button {
                    } label: {
                        Circle()
                            .frame(width: 8, height: 8)
                        Text("\(station.name) Station")
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        Text(station.name)
                    }
                    .padding(8)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class FeatureFViewModel: NSObject, ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedDetentIdentifier: UISheetPresentationController.Detent.Identifier
    
    init(
        selectedDetentIdentifier: UISheetPresentationController.Detent.Identifier = .medium
    ) {
        self.selectedDetentIdentifier = selectedDetentIdentifier
    }
}

extension FeatureFViewModel: UISheetPresentationControllerDelegate {
    func sheetPresentationControllerDidChangeSelectedDetentIdentifier(_ sheetPresentationController: UISheetPresentationController) {
        if let selectedDetentIdentifier = sheetPresentationController.selectedDetentIdentifier {
            self.selectedDetentIdentifier = selectedDetentIdentifier
        }
    }
}

struct FeatureFView: View {
    @ObservedObject var featureFViewModel: FeatureFViewModel
    
    init(
        featureFViewModel: FeatureFViewModel
    ) {
        self.featureFViewModel = featureFViewModel
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Feature F")
            
            if featureFViewModel.selectedDetentIdentifier == .large {
                FeatureIView()
            } else {
                Text("large")
            }
        }
    }
}
```